# BIOS reset when Computer turned off

Tags: motherboard, bios

My PC BIOS resets to factory settings when I turn off the computer.

I know that this problem usually is related to the BIOS battery, but I bought a new battery and changed it but the problem still remains.

Is there another reason?

Comment: If a new BIOS battery did not work, then there could be something wrong between the battery and the board (ie, a damaged component on the board).

Comment: Check the clear CMOS jumper. Make sure the replacement battery is properly installed. Make sure the replacement battery isn't dead.

Comment: @MaQleod:explain more....Which of them is likely to damaged??

Comment: @JesonPark: Could be anything. Look for physical distress, as in bent, broken, or burned.